# compare two date using php and if

Tags: php

i have a problem with php

```
$filename = "../ajax_php/5.jpg";
$tanggal = date("d-m-Y", filemtime($filename));
echo $tanggal . "<br/>"; //  26-06-2013

$add_days = 3;
$baru = date('d-m-Y',strtotime($tanggal) + (24*3600*$add_days));
echo $baru . "<br/>"; //  29-06-2013

$skrg = date('d-m-Y');
echo $skrg . "<br/>"; //  07-12-2013

if($baru < $skrg){
    echo "<br/> yes";
}
```

when i compare 2 date using if `$baru < $skrg` that should be get output yes, but i fail to get the output

can someone help me?? how to compare 2 date using php??

Comment: `filemtime` returns a unix timestamp. you should probably use that format. Alternatively, look into using `DateTime` PHP class to create  date/time objects - these can be compared transparently, and it contains are more reliable inbuilt ways to add/subtract time from a date.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot compare dates straight away, but you're on the right track with strtotime. What you need to do is compare both dates in Unix time, and then make sure that they aren't the same date but with different seconds.

```
$baru = strtotime($tanggal) + (24*3600*$add_days);
$skrg = time();
if ($baru < $skrg && date('Y-m-d', $baru) != date('Y-m-d', $skrg)) {
    // do stuff
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try This  (only numbers are easy to compare):-

---

```
$date1 = strtotime('29-06-2013');
$date2 = strtotime('07-12-2013');

if($date1 < $date2){
    echo "<br/> yes";
}
```

---